# Is there a way to get the positions of unknown elements of a square matrix in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to write code that prints out the elements in a "chain" based on the positions. The matrix is symmetric, so I am just looking at the elements above the diagonal.

For example, element (0,1) and (1,2) print out next to each other because they have a common `1.`

Is there a way to get the positions of the elements in the matrix so that I could use loops to place the correct elements next to each other?

In the following image, the ordering is a bit clearer than it is in words. The numbers are the positions of the elements in row, column format. In chain 2, element 13 is skipped over until element 14 is reached as that is the common number.
[image]

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Are you trying to iterate over the elements which are above the diagonal in a row by row fashion? Or -- is the ordering that you are envisioning more complex?

Comment: What's your code, have you tried something?

Comment: There are numerous chains that can be made with 2-element subsets where consecutive chain entries have an intersection of size 1. For example `(0,1) => (0,2) => (1,2)` vs. `(0,1) => (1,2) => (0,2)`. Thus -- your proposed ordering is under-specified.

Comment: @JohnColeman I have added an image that makes it a bit more clear

Comment: Still not very clear. It isn't at all clear how this would generalize to larger matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
import numpy as np
in_array = np.array([[0,1,1],[0,0,2],[0,0,0]])
# Select just the upper triangle
indx1, indx2 = np.triu_indices(3, k=1)
vals = in_array[indx1,indx2]
uvals = np.unique(vals)
for val in uvals:
    indx = np.where(vals == val)[0]
    print(val, list(zip(indx1[indx],indx2[indx])))
```

which outputs:

```
1 [(0, 1), (0, 2)]
2 [(1, 2)]
```